# How to make 30+ labels colide with my "player" label that is moveable?

Tags: c#, label

Is there a way to group 30+ labels to be able to control them all at once. What I want to do is this with 30 labels.

```
if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label1.Bounds))
        {
            if (right == true)
            {
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            else if (left == true)
            {
                left = false;
                right = true;
            }
            else if (up == true)
            {
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            else if (down == true)
            {
                down = false;
                up = true;
            }
```

And then where the label1 is checking if it is colided I want it to check all 30 labels if they have colided. And preferably not with 30x this code and just change the number. =)

I just want to add this is a maze game and the left, right etc. is the players movement defined outside what I posted here. I hope you understand!

All of my code:

```
    namespace mazeGame
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool down;
    bool left;
    bool right;
    bool up;
 //   new List<int> blocks = new List[5];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label10.Bounds))
        {

        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = true;
            left = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = true;
            down = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = true;
            down = false;
            right = false;
            left = false;

        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = true;
            up = false;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            right = true;
            left = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            left = true;
            right = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            up = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            down = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            down = true;
            left = false;
            up = false;
            right = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label1.Bounds))
        {
            if (right == true)
            {
                right = false;
                left = true;
            }
            else if (left == true)
            {
                left = false;
                right = true;
            }
            else if (up == true)
            {
                up = false;
                down = true;
            }
            else if (down == true)
            {
                down = false;
                up = true;
            }
        }

        var labels = this.??????? // here is where i need help.

        if (right == true)
        {
            player.Left += 1;
        }
        if (left == true)
        {
            player.Left -= 1;
        }
        if (up == true)
        {
            player.Top -= 1;
        }
        if (down == true)
        {
            player.Top += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry yes this is winforms and i am a begginer in c#.
Edit; not using XNA or such just basic windows forms.

Comment: how did you update it?

Comment: with a timer set on 1 ms

Comment: Do you want my entire code? its not so long atm just 140rows

Comment: what about keeping the labels inside an array? and itereting

Comment: Game in windows forms, using standard controls.. Sounds way too original: dodging moving labels and textboxes, while bringing all checkboxes into a listbox. =D

Comment: Any movement on this? Was my answer able to help you? Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers, i have been away from this project for 2 days but now i am back. I will try with your method paqogomez, thankyou!

Comment: And yes there is movement. Not on the labels but the player is moving with a timer and keyDown keyUp etc.

Comment: @user3480405 did my answer help?  Please be sure to upvote and mark as such if it did.  I'm happy to answer other questions if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OfType` will get all controls of the same type from a control.  In this case it will be labels from your form:

```
var labels = this.myForm.Controls.OfType<Label>()
```

Then you can iterate through your collection of labels.

EDIT:

Then, looping through your code it would look like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var labels = this.Form1.Controls.OfType<Label>()
   foreach(var label in labels)
   {
      if(player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label.Bounds))

//...
```

Comment: `OfType`, not `TypeOf`

Comment: Ehm, I'm a bit lost, what am i suposed to do with this? As stated before I am a beginner and I really can't comprehend what that code can be used for. Thank you!

Comment: @user3480405, check my edits.  The foreach loop should then test every label on your form and set the proper right or left var.

Comment: As a side note, i'm not sure why you move on both the keydown AND keyup.  You might want to look into the `keypress` event

Comment: Thank you I will try this right now, and also fix the keyup and keydown movement. silly of me:
EDIT: Okay and here is the next problem. Since my player is a label i cant move. Or at least i think that is why i just stand still when i start and press move buttons.

Comment: That sounds like a new question. Probably best to mark answers, upvote and compose a new question. Good luck!

Comment: @Burmeister Great little app.  I sent a few upvotes your way.  Send some back :)

Comment: This is such gold, reading this back I realize how far I've come. I am now working as a Dynamics 365 Consultant doing a webapp here and there. Thanks for the help back then @paqogomez

Comment: @Burmeister haha!  Thanks, i dont go begging for upvotes anymore, so perhaps we've both progressed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As for me it is good decision to create array or even list (witch you can dynamically update) of all your 30+ labels and then to manipulate them in one short method. Of course, if the actions as much simple as you write up and nothing else.

Comment: Okay, and what would be an easy method to do this?